# How to Convert Immutable MultiDict to a dataframe

Tags: pandas, forms, flask

I have a form which posts back (req) an ImmutableMultiDict which I have pasted below:

*ImmutableMultiDict([('HT_Goals', '3'), ('HT_Goals', '3'), ('HT_Goals', '1'), ('HT_Goals', '0'),   ('AT_Goals', '5'), ('AT_Goals', '1'), ('AT_Goals', '7'), ('AT_Goals', '1')])*

I am trying to convert it into a Dataframe which looks like this:

| Index | HT_Goals | AT_Goals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 7 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |

It might be this is not possible and it might be that I am structuring the underlying form wrong.

I have tried various ways of addressing it and just seem to be going round in circles. My latest code is as following but only returns the first row. I cant work out a way of looping through them

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        req = request.form
        print(req)
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(req, orient ='index')
        return render_template('onetable.html', tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')],titles=df.columns.values,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of worked it out. At least enough to access the dict which will enable me to develop the table I am after. The new code is:

```
        req = request.form

        df = pd.DataFrame(list(req.items(1)),columns = ['Team','Goals'])
```

The addition of the (1) makes it pass all the values to the DF. Although (0) or no ()  only passes the first line. Not sure why that is but it's working!